# Rate-Limit Kafka Mirroring

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Is there any option to throttle/rate-limit the [MirrorMaker](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330) process so that the target cluster always lag behind the source cluster,in a predictable way?

Does this option `--num.streams` help to throttle the flow?

I have to throttle and maintain the lag on the target cluster, so it enables the consumers to switch to target cluster with ease, without missing any messages to process.

My consumers can handle duplicates in messages. But I also dont want them to consume messages from the beginning/earliest.

Kafka Version is : 0.9

Comment: The target cluster will always be behind the source cluster. What does `kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh` say? If lag is low, you shouldn't have any problem. Yes `num.streams` and `num.producers` can help if you are not keeping up with the source. What is the actual problem? Could you develop on why rate-limiting it to _enable consumers to switch to target cluster with ease_?

Comment: @jjmontes, the alternate option would be to stop the mirroring and on-board the consumers after some time, start the mirroring so that no messages are missed/skipped for processing.

Comment: Mirrormaker does not have such parameters. The num.streams parameter in your case will not help you, that is, using this parameter you will not be able to get a deterministic stream lag

Comment: @Andrey, Thank you. In that case, I believe we have to stop/start the mirroring OR take a random point-in-time offset and let consumers start from there.

Comment: The right solution would be to optimize the consumers for speed or increase them in quantity, and allow the Mirrormaker to deliver messages without lag.

Comment: Agree @Andrey but the requirement here is to port/switch the consumers to the new target cluster from source cluster, without missing any messages to process.

Comment: That isn't really possible with MirrorMaker unless you actually know timestamps to seek to, since offsets are not guaranteed to match. However, offset time seeking wasn't implemented until Kafka 0.11.